# Control on "Force Stop" and "Uninstall" button of Android Device

Tags: android

I am new to Android App development.I want to get event on the  force stop and uninstall  button of Android device (menu button --> settings --> Application -->Manage Application --> ).
So after clicking on force stop and uninstall button I want to do some functionality. So how to do it.How to do this ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

That is  not possible,  sorry...

Answer (score 1):

You can not control force stop or uninstall but you can find if your app is uninstalled.
just write another app and check if your old app package exists.

```
public boolean isPackageExists(String targetPackage){
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
        pm = getPackageManager();        
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage)) return true;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible as open as android is.

Comment: Or to clarify, android has strong rules about what applications are and aren't allowed to do.  As for the openness of the platform itself, on most consumer-destined devices, android is basically "read only" open source.  Only a minority of devices let you install a customized version of android without first finding a way to "break into" the version that came on your phone from the factory.